# how do I prevent a popout menu div from displacing other content divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a hidden popout menu that toggles its visibility on the click of a button. When the popout menu becomes visible it displaces the main content to the bottom of the page. The idea would be to have the popout menu is displayed over the content div.

**HTML:**

```
<!------- Pop out menu for Side Navigation Bar ------->
<div class = "popout_navbar_align_center">
    <div class = "menu_nav_inner align-center pad-2">
        <ul>
            <li><button class="static_nav_btn"><a href="#">THE MISSION</a></button></li>
            <li><button class="static_nav_btn"><a href="#">OUR WORK</a></button></li>
            <li><button class="static_nav_btn"><a href="#">WHO WE ARE</a></button></li>
            <li><button class="static_nav_btn"><a href="#">MISS ROSIE</a></button></li>
            <li><button class="static_nav_btn"><a href="#">SCHOLARSHIP</a></button></li>
            <li><button class="static_nav_btn"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></button></li>
        </ul>
        
        <div class="box">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-white btn-animation-1">DONATE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>


<!------- Hamburger Top Navigation Bar for 768px and smaller screens ------->
<div class = "navBar_top">
    <div class = "hamburger-bar-center" id ="topNavId" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
</div>


<!------- Main body ------->
<main id="content" class="flex-grow">
    <div id="homepage-banner">
        <div class="page-banner">
            <h2 class="small-hidden">
                FOUNDATION
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

**CSS:**
**(Popout menu)**

```
.popout_navbar_align_center {
    background-image: url("Assets/Textures/sandpaper.png");
    background-color:;
    width: 240px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.popout_navbar_align_center .menu_nav_inner {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT: **

```
$("#sideNavId").on("click", function() {

         
         
         if($(".popout_navbar_align_center").is(":visible"))
         {
             $(".popout_navbar_align_center").hide("slow");
         }
         else {
             $(".popout_navbar_align_center").show("slow");
         }
         
     });
```

I've tried manipulating the css for the main content div but everything I've tried doesn't seem to work in regards to that approach. I'm not sure which divs properties should be manipulated to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `top` and `left` css values along with `position: absolute` to achieve your popup not moving the rest of the content, but instead floating in front of it